# I want to write to a certain line on a txt using php

Tags: php, html, fwrite

What i want:

```
file.txt:
Name: sam
email: email@email.com
```

so i have this

```
<?php
    $myFile = "file.txt";
    $txt = 'thetxt';
    $file = file($myFile);
    foreach ($file as $row_num => $row) {
        //idk what i should do here
    }
    $file_o = fopen($myFile, "w");
    fwrite($file_o, $txt);
    fclose($file_o);
?>
```

Basically i want to have 2  and with a submit button i will be setting the text as a $string and then this will go to the appropriate line on the txt file.

Comment: What constitutes ___the correct line on the .txt file___

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: `//idk what i should do here` We too.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Your File name with extension
$fileName = "file.txt";

//text you want to add in file
$txt = "Name: sam" . PHP_EOL . "email: email@email.com" . PHP_EOL ;

//Save file
$myfile = file_put_contents($fileName , $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```